# printing data as hexdump in perl

Tags: perl, escaping, hexdump

I am trying to print data as hexdump in perl but looks like its only working when i am "hard coding" the variable with hex dump value. In below code, hexdump is printed for first case but for second case ($var2), it just prints the data that is read from the file handle

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
$var = "\xE9\x92\x97\xAF\xE9\x92\x97\xB5";
print "the first dumper is\n";
print Dumper($var);
my $filename = 'c.txt';
open($fh, "<", $filename);
{
local $/;
$var2 = <$fh>;
chop($var2);
}
close($fh);
$var5 = $var2;
print "the second dumper is\n";
print Dumper($var5);
```

The output of above code is

```
[root@abc]# perl code.pl
```

the first dumper is

```
$VAR1 = 'é’—¯é’—µ';
```

the second dumper is

```
$VAR1 = '"\\xE9\\x92\\x97\\xAF\\xE9\\x92\\x97\\xB5"';
```

It looks like perl is appending an extra backslash with every slash present in the filehandle input. How can i print the file handle data as hexdump? The contents of c.txt file are

```
[root@abc]# cat c.txt 
"\xE9\x92\x97\xAF\xE9\x92\x97\xB5"
```

Comment: I think you want pack and unpack, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html. But I'm having trouble figuring out if you want the first or the second output. Or are you just trying to figure out what is happening?

Comment: @Dan, i want the first output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
$var = "\xE9\x92\x97\xAF\xE9\x92\x97\xB5";
print "the first dumper is\n";
print Dumper($var);
my $filename = 'c.txt';
open($fh, "<", $filename);
{
local $/;
$var2 = <$fh>;
chop($var2);
}
close($fh);
$var5 = $var2;
$var5 =~ s/"|\\x//g;
print "the second dumper is\n";
print Dumper(pack("H*",$var5));
```

I'm using search and replace to remove all the " chars and the \x as these are just cruft used to help make it human readable. Then pack it as a hex string.